# (Very) Twisted bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold. Over each coordinate chart $(U,\varphi)$ $M$ looks like euclidean space. In particular the tangent bundle $TM$ is trivial over $M$. So you the covering of $M$ by "trivialisations" of $TM$ is *at most* as rich as the covering of $M$ by charts. One can argue similarly for any vector bundle over $M$. However it may happen that $M$ is complicated but has trivial tangent bundle so the covering of $M$ by trivialisation consists from only one element.

> Is it true that for each (say closed) manifold $M$ one can find a vector bundle $E \to M$ such that each trivialization $U$ of $E$ the manifold $M$ is euclidean over $U$?

Comment: Do you want to ask: Does there exists a $E$ so that If $\{U_\alpha\}$ trivializes $E$, then $U_\alpha$ must be homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's my question

Comment: A trivial example would be the Mobius band on $\mathbb S^1$.... (And indeed, all nontrivial bundles on $S^n$ too.

Comment: @JohnMa More generally, any nontrivial bundle on a sphere.

Comment: @JohnMa (which you apparently edited your comment to say)

Comment: It seems there are some problem in SE now, some functions/bottom just don't quite work. The edit is done before your comment (may be you find the other way round) @MattSamuel

Comment: @JohnMa I was editing my comment after I saw your comment posted, and when I posted my comment it refreshed and showed your edit. Normal behavior as far as I can tell; refresh is not automatic.